# How can I prefill taxonomy tags for a new node being created through the node form?

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms

I have created a cck node type and associated a tagging taxonomy vocabulary with it. When users create new content, I would like to be able to prepopulate the node form.

For example, if the node type were 'cars' and one term was 'antique', I want to be able to create new instances of cars with the tag 'antique' already populated in the editing form.

I have gotten as far as creating a path such as `'node/add/auto?tid=3'` ... but how do I then take that tid and use it to prepopulate the vocabulary tags field in the auto_node_form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Prepopulate](http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate) module.

[Read the documentation](http://drupal.org/node/228167) on how to use it.

Comment: Super, this worked great. I also found this issue which shows how to use it for various use cases: http://drupal.org/node/81756